# Why does this sequence of await function calls run in the wrong order?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I want to output some text after 2 seconds first, after output some "alert()" second and at the end output some "console.log" by using only async/await. Please help me how to write such a sequence?

Why the code below does not work

```
async function qaz()
{
    let res1 = await setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("show me first");
    }, 2000);
    let res2 = await alert('show me second');
    let res3 = await console.log('show me at the end');
    return [res1,res2,res3];
}
```

Comment: There is absolutley no reason to use `async / await`. This code is just using `await` without knowing what it does

Comment: I suggest you read [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), which has demo code similar to yours, but done right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither the `setTimeout`, the `alert`, or the `console.log` return promises, and that's a problem because `await` only works with promises.

You can still use `async/await`, however. Create a `delay` function that returns a promise you *can* `await` for the first part, and then after that resolves do your alerts and your logging.

```js
function delay(n) {
  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(() => res(), n);
  });
}

async function qaz() {
  await delay(2000);
  console.log('Show me first');
  alert('Show me second');
  console.log('Show me at the end');
}

qaz();
```

Answer (score 4):

The `setTimeout` is part of the JavaScript asynchronous methods (methods that are starting to execute and their result will return sometime in the future to a component called the callback queue, later to be executed)

What you probably want to do is to wrap the `setTimeout` function within a Promise and await it and then execute the rest of the synchronous code.

```js
const longTask = () => new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("show me first");
        resolve();
    }, 2000);
});
  
async function qaz()
{   
    await longTask();
    alert('show me second');
    console.log('show me at the end');
}

qaz();
```

I suggest to read more about the event loop model [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

Comment: I will modify the script. I agree no need to return anything from `qaz`

Comment: Was something not clear so that you change the acceptance of the answer @Shahkumar41?